# Intel IACA analyzer alters assembly?

Tags: assembly, simd, avx2, iaca

I wanted to run some code through IACA analyzer to see how many uops it was using-- I started with a simple function to see if it was working..

Unfortunately when I insert the macros IACA says to use, the resulting assembly was very different, and so any analysis of it is not helpful..

Here is the assembly produced without IACA

```
00007FF9CD590580  vaddps      ymm1,ymm5,ymmword ptr [rax]  
00007FF9CD590584  vaddps      ymm2,ymm6,ymmword ptr [rax+20h]  
00007FF9CD590589  vaddps      ymm3,ymm7,ymmword ptr [rax+40h]  
00007FF9CD59058E  vmulps      ymm4,ymm1,ymm1  
00007FF9CD590592  vfmadd231ps ymm4,ymm2,ymm2  
00007FF9CD590597  vfmadd231ps ymm4,ymm3,ymm3  
00007FF9CD59059C  vcmpgt_oqps ymm1,ymm4,ymm9  
00007FF9CD5905A2  vrsqrtps    ymm0,ymm4  
00007FF9CD5905A6  vandps      ymm2,ymm1,ymm0  
00007FF9CD5905AA  vmovups     ymm3,ymm8  
00007FF9CD5905AF  vfmsub231ps ymm3,ymm2,ymm4  
00007FF9CD5905B4  vmovups     ymmword ptr [r9+rax],ymm3  
00007FF9CD5905BA  add         rax,rcx  
00007FF9CD5905BD  sub         r8d,1  
00007FF9CD5905C1  jne         fm::EvlOp::applyLoop<`RegisterShapeOps<fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> > >'::`2'::doDISTANCE_SPHERE_11,fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> >::DataWrapper,fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> >::RegisterBlock,fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> >::instruction_input>+0B0h (07FF9CD590580h)
```

And here is what it produces once I add the IACA macros..( I'm testing MSVC produced binary, so I'm using IACA_VC64_START and IACA_VC64_END as the manual says to do).

```
00007FF9CD59058B  vmovups     ymm2,ymmword ptr [rax+40h]  
00007FF9CD590590  vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rax]  
00007FF9CD590594  vmovups     ymm1,ymmword ptr [rax+20h]  
00007FF9CD590599  vaddps      ymm3,ymm2,ymm8  
00007FF9CD59059E  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp+20h],ymm0  
00007FF9CD5905A3  vaddps      ymm0,ymm0,ymm6  
00007FF9CD5905A7  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp+40h],ymm1  
00007FF9CD5905AC  vmulps      ymm4,ymm0,ymm0  
00007FF9CD5905B0  vaddps      ymm1,ymm1,ymm7  
00007FF9CD5905B4  vfmadd231ps ymm4,ymm1,ymm1  
00007FF9CD5905B9  vfmadd231ps ymm4,ymm3,ymm3  
00007FF9CD5905BE  vcmpgt_oqps ymm1,ymm4,ymm5  
00007FF9CD5905C3  vrsqrtps    ymm0,ymm4  
00007FF9CD5905C7  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp+60h],ymm2  
00007FF9CD5905CC  vandps      ymm2,ymm1,ymm0  
00007FF9CD5905D0  vmovups     ymm3,ymm9  
00007FF9CD5905D5  vfmsub231ps ymm3,ymm2,ymm4  
00007FF9CD5905DA  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rcx+rax],ymm3  
00007FF9CD5905DF  add         rax,rdx  
00007FF9CD5905E2  mov         qword ptr [rbp+18h],rax  
00007FF9CD5905E6  vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp+80h],ymm3  
00007FF9CD5905EE  sub         r8d,1  
00007FF9CD5905F2  jne         fm::EvlOp::applyLoop<`RegisterShapeOps<fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> > >'::`2'::doDISTANCE_SPHERE_11,fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> >::DataWrapper,fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> >::RegisterBlock,fm::interpeter<fm::interpreter_settings<math::v8float,4,float,fm::Instruction,math::v8f2d,math::v8float> >::instruction_input>+0B2h (07FF9CD590582h)
```

So it has inserted lots of moves, and now my (hopefully) fused add is not longer fused--..

I was hoping it would be able to tell me if

```
00007FF9CD590584  vaddps      ymm2,ymm6,ymmword ptr [rax+20h]
```

Stayed fused, but it removed this code all together..

Is this a known issue, or perhaps because I'm using MSVC which may not be very common?

Is there perhaps a way to fix this, or a better tool that is compatible with MSVC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IACA mark macros are just inline asm (or for 64-bit MSVC: start = `__writegsbyte(111, 111);` and stop = `222`).  They can potentially disturb the optimizer, or end up in the wrong place (e.g. not the last instruction before falling into a loop, so the block includes some loop setup).

If that happens, like in your case, your best bet is to ask the compiler to produce asm (not machine code) output, and **manually insert the markers into the asm you want to analyze.**

---

In NASM syntax, I use this `%if` / `%else` block so I can build with `nasm -DIACA_MARKS` or not.  I know this isn't the right syntax for MASM, but the IACA start/end markers are pretty simple: `mov` to EBX and `fs addr32 nop`.

```
%ifdef IACA_MARKS

%macro  IACA_start 0             ; NASM macro with 0 args, defines IACA_start
     mov ebx, 111
     db 0x64, 0x67, 0x90
%endmacro
%macro  IACA_end 0
     mov ebx, 222
     db 0x64, 0x67, 0x90
%endmacro

%else
%define IACA_start
%define IACA_end
%endif
```

Comment: Apparently IACA uses `__writegsbyte(111, 111)` for IACA_VC64_START, which should actually disturb the code less than trashing EBX would.

Comment: @RossRidge: For 32-bit MSVC, the IACA header uses `__emit` so the compiler isn't "aware" of trashing EBX, and shouldn't affect the optimizer.  Although actually it uses `__asm  mov ebx, x`, only emit for the other bytes.  But anyway, for GNU C inline asm it uses only a `"memory"` clobber, intentionally not telling the compiler about registers.  I think it intentionally wants to crash so you don't accidentally use IACA-marked executables in production or run benchmarks on them, when they have extra bloat around the hottest loops in your program.

Comment: Hmm, ok IACA-2.1's `iacaMarks.h` used to also include `ud2` before the begin mark, and after the end mark.  But they seem to have removed that in later versions.

Comment: When I Google searched for it, what came up was `__asm mov ebx, x` for 32-bit Visual C++, but that was from some project's header file that copied the macros, so I don't know what version of IACA it was from or if it's accurate.

Comment: @RossRidge: Yes, that is still what IACA has for 32-bit MSVC, only using `__asm __emit` for the `nop`.  (I should have rewritten the first part of my earlier comment instead of just adding a correction after checking the header >.<)  But for compilers that support GNU C inline asm, it trashes EBX without telling the compiler; that's what I was thinking of.